# Table is too wide

Tags: html, css

In this  [site page](http://www.indiacustomercare.com/mts-customer-care-contact-helpline-call-center-numbers) you can see that the table in the middle of page is too wide and is extending beyond it's parent div. 

 How to correct it? Any suggestions!

Comment: That page is not available anymore and doesn't show a table that "is too wide and is extending beyond it's [sic] parent div". Voting to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reduce the size and/or amount of the content in the table.  No amount of css or width attributes will reduce the size of the table if it is already at the minimum width that will contain the content.

**EDIT**

As suggested by Projapti, if you don't mind having a scrollbar on the page, adding a CSS `overflow-x:scroll` to the containing div will prevent the table from overflowing.  However, I would further suggest that you wrap an additional div around just the table, so that only the table will be scrolled content.  Have a look at the live preview below to see the effect.

[Live preview ->](http://jsbin.com/iziga4/edit#preview)

**EDIT 2**

Here's an example of the table contained within a height-adjusted div, as mentioned in one of my comments below:

[Live preview 2 ->](http://jsbin.com/ucacu4/edit#preview)

Comment: Can I add scrolling to it's parent div?

Comment: Yes, that would be another viable option.  @Projapati's suggestion should work if that is the route you want to take.

Comment: thanks, Live preview is very nice but I don't see scrollbars around the table.

Comment: it's way down at the bottom of the table, which is quite tall.  if you want a scrollbar on the side as well, set a specific height on the containing div, and change the css property to `overflow: scroll`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to add this on the parent div: style="overflow-x:scroll"

```
<div id="mts" class="icc telecom" style="overflow-x:scroll">
```

In my test in ff, it scrolls...

Comment: I was going to post a similar answer. If you don't have the option to reduce the table, use the `overflow-x:scroll` method sugested above.

Answer (score 0):

No magical CSS needed. You need to redesign the table so that the headings are along the X axis.